# CSS Transition making a image move up and down on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/os34f.jpg

I have this image and know i need to use css transition to make the vinyl move down when scrolled over? How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply `position:relative` to the "vinyl" element, then on its hover state, set `top:#px`.

For example:

```
#vinyl {
 position: relative;
 /* transition properties here */
}

#vinyl:hover {
 top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest way only involves one element with two backgrounds. The cover is the one on top and the other one is the vinyl itself.

On `hover`, you simply change the `background-position` of the second item.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3433187)

HTML is just:

```
<div class='vinyl'></div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
.vinyl {
    width: 109px;
    height: 162px;
    margin: 135px auto;
    background: url(http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/7524/albumm.jpg) 
            no-repeat 0 100%,
        radial-gradient(circle, transparent 3%, navy 4%, navy 5%, #4774a2 5%, 
                #4774a2 8%, navy 8%, navy 9%, #4774a2 10%, #4774A2 20%, 
                black 21%, #1c1c1c, black 69%, transparent 70%) 
            no-repeat 50% 0%;
    background-size: 109px 109px;
    transition: .65s;
}
.vinyl:hover {
    background-position: 0 100%, 50% 95%;
}
```

---

If you want the transition to happen only on hover on the vinyl itself (no `transition` on `hover` on the cover), then you'll need to use two elements.

[**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3433239) - I've made `.vinyl` a child of `.cover`, gave it positioning and set its `z-index` to `-1` (so that it would go under the cover).

HTML is now:

```
<div class='cover'>
    <div class='vinyl'></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
.cover {
    width: 111px;
    height: 111px;
    margin: 135px auto;
    background: url(http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/7524/albumm.jpg);
}
.vinyl {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -49%; left: 1.5%;
    width: 109px;
    height: 109px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: radial-gradient(transparent 3%, navy 4%, navy 5%, #4774a2 5%, 
                #4774a2 8%, navy 8%, navy 9%, #4774a2 10%, #4774A2 20%, 
                black 21%, #1c1c1c, black 69%, transparent 70%) no-repeat 50% 0%;
    background-size: 109px 109px;
    transition: .65s;
}
.vinyl:hover { top: -3%; }
```